# Organized library with Fortran functions

Tags: function, module, fortran

I am trying to make a library of useful functions. I yet don't know much about this, but apparently most of them, if not all, need to be included in a module (or in a interface inside the program, but since the point of this is to make a library, that doesn't seem to be a choice) or else the programs in which I'll use them won't recognize them.

I could make a long file with one module including all this functions, but I would like to keep the different functions in different short files. If I do this, however, I would have to make a different module for each function, and If I want to use them all in a program, I would have a very long `USE` declaration list (not to mention the number of .mod files that would be produced).

The only possible solution for this I could come up with, was to make another module with just the `USE` declarations for all other modules, but I think there must be another way to have a library containing functions that is not so far fetched.

---

Also, why is it that I have this problem with functions but not with subroutines? Is it because the command `CALL` immediately identifies the line as a subroutine call whereas functions are called just by name with no command to tell the compiler "hey, this is a function", so it has to know what is a function and what not beforehand?

---

I am including an example (following the instructions in http://www.oceanographers.net/forums/showthread.php?378-How-to-make-a-FORTRAN-library, and using the correct 'path').

TestFunc.F90

```
FUNCTION SumNum(nNum1,nNum2) RESULT(nResult)  
IMPLICIT NONE  
INTEGER,INTENT(IN) :: nNum1,nNum2  
INTEGER            :: nResult  

nResult=nNum1+nNum2  

RETURN;END FUNCTION
```

TestProg.F90

```
PROGRAM TestProg  
IMPLICIT NONE  

WRITE(6,*) SumNum(2,2)  

STOP;END PROGRAM
```

Command Line

```
> gfortran -c TestFunc.F90 -o TestFunc.o  
> ar ruv libmylib.a *.o  
> gfortran TestProg.F90 -o Test.x -L/path -lmylib.a

TestProg.F90:6.12:  

    WRITE(6,*) SumNum(2,2)  
               1  
Error: Function 'sumnum' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

Answer (score 7):

My recommendation is to place both your functions and subroutines into a module, then use that module.   Place ones that are logically related into the same module.  Using one module per procedure seems very inconvenient -- why do you prefer this approach?  The reason to place procedures (functions and subroutines) into a module and then "use" that module is that it makes the interface "explicit" so that the compiler can check consistency between the actual arguments in call and the dummy arguments of the procedure.  This will find many types of bugs and save effort in your programming.   It is easy and automatic compared to writing a declaration ("interface"). You don't have to write the procedure declaration AND the interface, and you don't have to keep them consistent when revisions are made.   Yes, the "call" statement is helping the compiler identify subroutines, but the advantage of making the interface explicit via a module needs the module for both function and subroutine.

EDIT to answer comment: Yes, even if the procedures are being placed into a library, I'd place them into a single module.  If the procedures are totally unrelated, then they probably belong in separate libraries and separate modules.   If related, then in the same library and the same module.  Fortran provides features to manage possible "issues" with having many procedures in the same module: you can make clear which procedures you are using in a "use" statement and avoid name clashes by using an "only" clause, listing only the procedures that are used.  You can even rename a procedure that you want to use if the default name clashes with another name.

Comment: Even when the code is meant for a library? Isn't it better in this case to have all procedures separated so it is more easy to handle them?? (with the exception of different versions of the same procedures, like with overloaded ones) Isn't a library already supposed to be a compilation of logically related procedures, and if so, having modules wouldn't be kind of redundant? Do you keep your libraries subdivided into modules?? I am asking because I honestly ignore which is the best practice in this situations and why...

Comment: (Oh, and I clearly don't prefer to have a lot of single procedure modules; that is why I asked here if there was a way to incorporate functions without having to include them in a module =P. I also didn't know any advantage of having a procedure inside a module instead of outside of it, other than the cases where putting some procedures this way would cause an error)

Comment: But isn't it better to have single procedure files to make the library? Specially if you have a library with a lot of procedures; having all of them in the same file wouldn't be a little overwhelming when you want to make a modification or add something? Or do you think is usually better to have very few procedures per library? Or is there some way to keep the code for the procedures in different files and still make them be "contained" in one module?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to put subroutines in modules in order to make a library. What I usually do is have subroutines in separate files, build object files (.o) out of them, and then archive them into a library, e.g.:

```
ar ruv mylib.a *.o
```

Then all it takes is to specify mylib.a during linking with the main program which calls the subroutine. It does not make a difference whether your procedure is a subroutine or a function.

EDIT1:
Your main program needs to have a function declaration:

```
PROGRAM TestProg  
IMPLICIT NONE  
INTEGER :: sumnum

WRITE(6,*) SumNum(2,2)  

STOP;END PROGRAM
```

Then:

```
gfortran -c *.f90
ar ruv mylib.a testfunc.o
gfortran testprog.o -o x mylib.a
```

When I run x, I get correct output.

Comment: Are you declaring the function in some way inside the programs? My programs are still not recognizing the function. I have added in a second edit an example code that does not work.

Comment: @Nordico I updated the answer, would not fit in the comment box.

Comment: Ok. Although this eliminates the need to put things in modules and have a lot of .mod files, I still have to specify in all programs which functions I am going to use beforehand (Only that I declare them as variables instead of using "USE" with the appropriate mod). It is indeed much better, but I would like to know if there is a way of being able to call my functions just like any intrinsic fortran function: by calling the command, not having to make any previous declaration (just by linking the library in compile time).

Comment: Well, if you know you are using a certain function (before compile time, that is, coding time), then all it takes is to declare that function. Not needing to declare intrinsic functions like SQRT is just a mere convenience, and does not really have practical implications.

Comment: If you really don't want to code external function declarations, you could store all of the declarations in a separate module, put module in yourlib.a and use module at the beginning of the program. Which brings you back to square 1, where you might have as well put your function routines in the module.

Comment: Yeah, well, actually not exactly. It would be much better not having to do that, but I think that one module to declare is still preferable to a hundred modules with one function each and then one module to declare, which was my initial approach. I am wondering now how do intrinsic functions do to avoid this declaration and if you need to declare functions in the common fortran "standard" libraries that can be found (for example, in http://www.fortran.com/tools.html; I never used them, so I really don't know).

Comment: I still do not understand why do you want to avoid function declaration in the main program. Why it would be much better to not have to do that? Even if you have a program that generates your fortran code and you do not necessarilly know ahead which function you are going to use, it is trivial to add declaration of the function. If you still insist on not wanting to do this, see which .a file contains intrinsics for your compiler and add your object files to this library. You will most probably need root permission to do this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3872/discussion-between-nordico-and-iro-bot)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question regarding the difference between function and subroutine with the implicit interfaces: functions are used like variables, and there type needs to be known, thus you need to declare them with the external attribute.
However, I also would strongly recommend M. S. B.s answer, that you should put everything into modules, by this you get explicit interfaces for all your routines, and such problems are avoided. One more comment, the return statement in your sample code is unnecessary, as well as the stop.